# Dismiss a View Controller with a UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, dismiss

I'm trying to present a log out alert. When the user taps on *Yes*, I want my view controller to dismiss with a method that can provide me a completion handler.

The view controller is inside a navigation controller and is the second one on the stack.

I came up with the following code:

```
@IBAction func logOut() {
        let logOutAlert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Log out", message: "Are you sure ?", preferredStyle:.Alert)

        logOutAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            //Present entry view ==> NOT EXECUTED
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
        })

        logOutAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(logOutAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The line `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)` is read but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that `dismissViewControllerAnimated` doesn't do anything for you because the view controller isn't presented modally, but shown by way of a navigation controller. To dismiss is, you can tell the navigation controller to pop it from the stack, like so:

```
    logOutAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        })
```

Unfortunately, `popViewControllerAnimated` doesn't seem to provide a way to attach your own completion handler out of the box. If you require one, you could still add one by utilising the associated `CATransaction`, which could look something like this:

```
    logOutAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(/* YOUR BLOCK GOES HERE */)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        CATransaction.commit()
        })
```